# Background Image "Failed to load url" from CSS in MVC4 deployed in IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc-3, background-image

In my MVC application, I refered a CSS file to render a background image for the page.
I tried with all types of possibilities such as

```
background: url(../Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
background: url(../../Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
background: url(~/Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
background: url(./Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top; works only in Firefox
background: url(/Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;

background-image: url(/Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
background-image: url(../Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
background-image: url(../../Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
background-image: url(~/Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
background-image: url(./Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
```

But It shows failed to load the given url and network error 404 in both Firefox and IE9.
**CSS file** **login-box.css**

```
#login-box {
    width:333px;
    height: 352px;
    padding: 58px 76px 0 76px;
    color: #ebebeb;
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url(../Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
}
.reg_body
        {
            background-image: url(../Images/plain-blue-background-images-7117.jpg);
        }
```

The style reference in my View as

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/CSS/login-box.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Which is the correct format to render background image from CSS file to MVC View.
  I wonder why it doesnt accept anyformat when hosted in IIS.
 Any suggestions.

Comment: Assuming the images are valid images then this has something to do with your folder structure. Can you post the structure of your folders? Like is the Images folder on the same level as CSS?

Comment: Sounds like it should work!... Could it be that you are using a capitol "I" (Image folder)?

Comment: Why are you having so many ref. to the same image..? Try using just"background: url(../Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;" once.. it should work in all browsers

Answer (score 3):

Dont give this type of URL

```
background-image: url(../Images/plain-blue-background-images-7117.jpg);
```

use this one

```
background-image: url(/Images/plain-blue-background-images-7117.jpg);
```

if its not work...then try to remove slash /Images/ to Images/

Answer (score 1):

Move your `Images` folder to the `Content` folder, and use this in your CSS:

```
background-image: url(Images/login-box-backg.png) no-repeat left top;
```

Your folder structure should look like this:

- Content
  -- Images
  ---- login-box-backg.png
  -- Site.css